# How do I get aggregation among Maven projects

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to achieve the following (abstract):

/tmp/proj1:

```
- src/test/java/com/aDomain/proj1/Parent.java
- src/test/resources/aResource
- pom.xml
```

/tmp/proj1/pom.xml:

```
#..
<artifactId>proj1</artifactId>
<!-- Approach 1 -->
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
  <module>../proj2</module>
</modules>
<properties>
  <aResource>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/aResource</aResource>
</properties>
#..
```

/tmp/proj1/src/test/java/com.aDomain.proj1/Parent .java:

```
package com.aDomain.proj1;
public class Parent {
  public void fubar(){ System.out.println(System.getProperty("aResource"); } //exp: /tmp/proj1/src/test/resources/aResource
}
```

/tmp/proj2:

```
- src/test/java/com/aDomain/proj2/Child.java
- pom.xml
```

/tmp/proj2/pom.xml:

```
#..
<!-- Approach 1 -->
<parent>
  <artifactId>proj1</artifactId>
  <groupId>#..</groupId>
  <version>#..</version>
  <relativePath>../proj1/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
#..
<!-- Approach 2 -->
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>#..</groupId>
    <artifactId>proj1</artifactId>
    <version>#..</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

src/test/java/com/aDomain/proj2/Child.java:

```
package com.aDomain.proj2;
import com.aDomain.proj1;

public class Child extends Parent {}
```

So that new `Child().fubar()` prints `/tmp/proj1/src/test/resources/aResource`. After a considerable amound of tinkering I guess I need help. Setting `proj1` as a parent makes `Parent` inaccessible to `Child`. Setting it as a dependency renders `Parent` unable to build. Instead I want them do interdepend so that they rebuild top-down when something changes.

Comment: Do you have a link to the full project somewhere?

Comment: No, but I made one for you according to what I am trying: github.com/midorlo/tmp08468452.git